# Server2003 Domain Controller Crash and Unable to recover?

Tags: windows-server-2003

We have only domain controller on windows server 2003, suddenly it crashes and we have no option to recover it.

After crash we install Server 2008 on this machine and configure new Active Directory and created all the client users with same name and passwords from scratch.

My question is now is there any option so that we can join every client computer on the network automatically?

Or we have to join it manually on every client machine??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually most likely, but you can cal la remote script / WMI to execute the command line from one station.

Take it as a lesson to NEVER EVER have one DC only.

Comment: So what do you suggest make Additional DC with it or have Image or Clone Backups to restore it rightaway ?

Comment: Cloning a DC is pointless and likely to cause more problems that it solves @sajid - simply install Windows Server onto a second server system, join the domain, and then follow the steps to promote it to domain controller. However instead of creating a new domain, join the one you've already created.